# Awful High-Level Director: What Next?

Tags: manager, politics

I work within an engineering organization that seems to have a very weakly trained middle-management tier. My direct manager is *fantastic*, but they seem to be an exception in my view. Our HR polls us annually for scores on our feelings all over the place, and we all very consistently rate our engineering management as severely lacking. Recently, it was poor enough to demand a specific meeting from HR to ask for open feedback about this abysmal score overall.

However, there is a particular outlier. It is my own manager's manager, who I am often working with directly on various projects. I get the sense that my manager also resents this person as someone they report to.

Until recently, I was willing to chalk it up to my own individual experience. I am blessed to have worked with many engineering leaders I look up to, even when I would butt heads with them. The important element to me is empowerment, respect, curiosity, empathy, commitment, all sorts of things you'd normally expect from a good leader. I want to make it clear that I don't write off anyone I simply disagree with.

A recent team retrospective that this person did not bother to attend revealed several corroborations from other team members of:

- sexist comments
- steamrolling
- triangulation
- humiliation
- uncommunicated PTO during the main project launch

... all aimed squarely at this individual. I'm not joking, there was a spread of positive feedback across the team, but all the negative feedback seemed basically aimed exclusively at this person.

It's hitting a little different for me now, knowing that it's not just me. This is across several teams, beyond the engineering department—design, content, marketing, you name it.

My concern right now is: is someone this high up able to accept feedback? Is *their* manager interested in feedback? I suggested bringing this all up in a regularly scheduled skip-skip-level and my manager very explicitly warned me against doing so. As I said, I greatly respect this particular manager as an outlier, so I am conflicted.

Or, should I throw my hands up and just move on to the next job? The market is crazy right now, I know, but I think I could bear it for a few more months while I look. I lead a team and work with many others that this person touches, so I do feel a little professional obligation to at least try to do something, if I'm being honest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest listening to your manager  and let the things play out as they are.

Given general score all over the board, the higher management have all the information it needs to make a decision on their level and you should not single yourself out as a target.

Just use this information and tread lightly around that manager  :)

Answer (score 1):

We have no way of knowing whether this individual will accept feedback. Note that if they're bad enough that you're complaining, odds are that they won't unless that feedback comes from *their* manager, so this becomes a question of how high a skip-level meeting you are willing and able to arrange and how clearly (but politely and respectfully) you can communicate the issue at that level.

If you can't find ways to live with this job and work with this manager (remembering that you don't have to like someone to work effectively with them), moving on may indeed be your only option.

Comment: "We have no way of knowing whether this individual will accept feedback."


In my view, their absence from that meeting I mentioned was a strong signal that they were not interested in it. Maybe that's enough of a signal, but I suppose I'm holding out hope that there is still a mechanism in which they are willing to accept it.

"remembering that you don't have to like someone to work effectively with them"

This is a good reminder, one I often struggle with, so thanks for outlining it.

Comment: You're there, I'm not. This does not sound like someone who is likely to respond well to criticism from below, but I have only your description of the situation to work with.